# Merge [jme] and [java-me] tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Could someone merge [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) and [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me) tags, since [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) is synonym tag of [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me) on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It is not a synonym tag at the moment, though I agree, it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Following the manual cleanup by Marcelo, I merged [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) into [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me). All new questions tagged with [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) will be automatically retagged to use [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I did total manual cleanup of the [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) tag, retagging everything that was actually referring to the [jmonkeyengine](/questions/tagged/jmonkeyengine) tag.

Can a mod please add [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) as a synonym for [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me)?

Answer (score 1):

But [jme](/questions/tagged/jme) can also mean the [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/)! And it is used as such, so manual cleanup is advisable.

Comment: Is there currently a tag for jMonkeyEngine?

Comment: @Marcelo: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmonkeyengine).

Comment: I am starting to do manual cleanup of the [jme] tag, do you think this tag should disappear or just leave it as a synonym of [java-me] as the OP suggests?

Comment: @Marcelo: I think it should be bound against java-me, yes.